# Ajax/Rails create action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hello and thanks in advance. Rails noob here :)
I have a simple rails app where a user can create an article through ajax. When the "Create article" is clicked _article_form.html.erb and new.js.erb are rendered, but when i click submit form nothing happens. No article is created. Here is new.js.erb

```
m = $('.modal');
m.html('<%= j(render partial: 'article_form', locals: { articles: @articles }) %>');
m.modal('show');
```

Here is my ArticlesController

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.create(article_params)
  @articles = Article.all
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Here is the home.html.erb

```
...
<div id="article_list">
  <%= render partial: 'articles/article_list' %>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>
```

And my partials _article_form

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for @article, class: 'clearfix', remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and _article_list

```
<% if @articles.empty? %>
  <span class="text-warning">
    There are no articles yet!
  </span>
<% else %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">     
    <div class="panel-heading">Articles</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <%= article.title %></br>
      <%= article.body.truncate(25, separator: ' ') %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, my create.js.erb

```
$('#article_list').html('<%= j(render partial: 'articles/article_list') %>');
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

I have been searching/trying to figure this out for 2 days but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the html of your form you will notice that the submit button is out of scope of form tag. that's why when you click on submit button, no action happens.

Change your html in partial _article_form as following:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <%= simple_form_for @article, class: 'clearfix', remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```